# adding single quotes to helm value

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm

In my values.yaml file for helm, I am trying to create a value with quotes but when I run it, it gives a different result

**values.yaml**

```
annotation: '"ports": {"88":"sandbox-backendconfig"}}'

{{ .Values.annotation }}
```

what shows when I do dry run

```
"ports": {"88":"sandbox-backendconfig"}}
```

how can I make the single quotes around it show also

Comment: Have you tried `{{ .Values.annotation | quote }} `?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When the Helm YAML parser reads in the `values.yaml` file, it sees that the value of `annotation:` is a [single-quoted string](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2788097) and so it keeps the contents of the value without the outer quotes.

As the YAML spec suggests, you can include single quotes inside a single-quoted string by doubling the quote.  It might be more familiar to make this a [double-quoted string](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2787109) and use backslash escaping.  A third possibility is to make this into a [block scalar](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2793652), which would put the value on a separate line, but wouldn't require any escaping at all.

```yaml
annotation: '''"ports": {"88":"sandbox-backendconfig"}}'''
annotation: "'\"ports\": {\"88\":\"sandbox-backendconfig\"}}'"
annotation: >-
  '"ports": {"88":"sandbox-backendconfig"}}'
```

I'm not sure what context you're trying to use this in, but if this is a more structured format, you can use Helm's `toYaml` or `toJson` functions to build up the annotation value for you.

```yaml
# values.yaml
ports:
  '88': sandbox-backendconfig
```

```yaml
# templates/some-resource.yaml
annotations: {{ printf "\"ports\": %s" (toJson .Values.ports) | squote }}
```

Answer (score 15):

Check the method below,

Values.yaml

```yaml
annotation: '"ports": {"88":"sandbox-backendconfig"}}'
```

Template

```
{{ .Values.annotation | squote }}
```

This should resolve your issue.

`squote` will put single quotes around the deduced value.

Comment: I had a completely unrelated problem, but `squote` saved me, thank you.